# How to delete parent and child records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create an ad-hoc delete query in SQL Server to delete parent/child/grandchild records from 3 tables based on a certain date.  However, there are no foreign key relationships defined in the database.

TableA keys on OrderID.  TableB keys on OrderID and ProductID and has child records to TableA based on OrderID.  TableC is keyed on OrderID, ProductID, ReleaseID and has child records to TableB based on OrderID and ProductID.

I want to delete records in all 3 tables based on an ExpirationDate in TableA.  Is there a way to accomplish this with a single delete query with joins?  Or, is this something better handled using a SP?

Thanks.

Comment: what about sql triggers?

Comment: i would suggest to use a transaction. so if you can't delete child - everything would be restored.
i would avoid using triggers, because a lot of people dont triat inserted/deleted as tables which cause issues on bulk inserts/updates.
or you can run inside sp, just start with grandchinld and up, and check if there any custom constrains